# Turning curve into mesh in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have made a geometry node that lets me draw a curve and makes geometry, like so:

[image]

[image]

Now this is fairly simple. But now I want to add stuff along the curve. Like a pattern of other geometry, preferably not just a displacement map (but that could work too). How do I go about this? Say adding smaller spheres all along the curve I've drawn.

I have tried to use the "instance to points" and then join it with the other, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You mean you want to distribute other objects on the vertices of the surface of the generated "tube"? What exactly didn't work when you tried _Instance on Points_? Because that's what I do. Or do you mean randomly distribute? Then the answer by LuckyOne should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use distribute on faces on instance on points like this:

[image]

then you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I must have put these in the wrong order. For some reason I think Instance to points should go first to define where the points are. :- ) Thanks!

Comment: Not at all!!!!!